# Firefox Add-on SDK and its compatibility?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

`install.rdf` in the Add-on SDK 1.16 package comes with minimum version of Firefox as 21.0. I changed it to 13.0 and developed an add-on, but still it is not compatible with below 21.0 versions.

Does this mean that minimum version cannot be modified?

How to develop an Add-on with Add-on SDK 1.16 (or recent) which will compatible with at least Firefox 13.0 onwards?

Comment: Definitely don't reduce the minimum version. The min version I suspect is calculated based on what parts of the SDK you use. If you use something meant for v21 it will absolutely fail in anything less.

Comment: By default install.rdf comes with the SDK package(it is already there before i start developing my first addon). I think there is no matter of "calculated install.rdf as per usage". So, any other alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Older versions of Firefox didn't ship the SDK in Firefox itself; instead libraries where shipped in the add-on XPI files.

Since the SDK libraries rely on a lot of ever changing Firefox internals, often on what used to be bleeding-edge stuff, the SDK team had to decide between adding compatibility layer upon layer to the libraries to support a wide range of old Firefox versions, or instead limit the amount of compatibility layers and just support a few recent (at the time) Firefox versions. They did the latter and hence the SDK usually did only officially support the current and one or two previous Firefox versions (for Firefox versions that did not ship the SDK themselves).

Since the SDK libraries are bundled with Firefox these days this isn't really a problem anymore. And IIRC that is where the `minVersion` of 21 you observed comes from: Firefox 21 was the first Firefox release that came bundled with stable SDK libraries.

So all this means that **you cannot use the SDK 1.16 and just mess with the `minVersion`**. The SDK libraries are simply not compatible with old Firefox versions and things will break. You could an use older SDK version that did support Firefox 13, but then your add-on will not work with more recent Firefox versions.
Also, since the SDK 1.15, the XPIs produced by the SDK do not even bundle the SDK libraries within the XPI anymore... Not that this matters, because even if you bundled the SDK libraries they still would not work with old Firefox versions correctly.

The only way to actually create add-ons that will work in such old Firefox versions but also in recent Firefox releases is to not use the SDK in the first place and instead create regular XUL-overlay and/or bootstrapped add-ons and come up with compatibility layers yourself.

Comment: Now everything is clear for me except that a statement "Add-on with older SDK will not work with more recent Firefox versions". But, My newly developed Add-on with SDK 1.14 (old?) working fine in Firefox 30.0 also. What it means?

Comment: Which versions of Firefox Support which versions of add-on SDK?
I could not find any clear compatibility table?